Can heterogeneous relations be reflexive / symmetric / transitive etc?
When introducing properties of relations such as reflexivity, symmetry, transitivity etc., it seems common to assume the relation $R$ is homogeneous (i.e. $R: A \to A$).[1]
However, this doesn't seem necessary, if the quantification is modified appropriately.
For example, given $A = \{1, 2, a\}$ and $B = \{ a, b \}$, then the relation $R = \{ (1,a), (a,a), (2,b)\}$ could be considered reflexive because $\forall x \in A \cap B, xRx$.
Similarly, instead of defining transitivity as:
$$\forall x,y,z \in A, xRy \land yRz \implies xRz$$
it could be generalized for a relation $S: A \to B$:
$$\forall x \in A, \forall y \in A \cap B, \forall z \in B, x S y \land y S z \implies x S z$$
Are these heterogenous versions correct? Or are these properties actually restricted to homogeneous relations, exclusively?
I can't tell if the restriction to homogeneous relations is part of the definition, or just reflects the relations commonly presented in an introductory course.

[1]: for example, the wikipedia page only mentions these properties under homogeneous binary relations; Mathematical Proofs by Chartrand et al. does the same; as does Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications, by Rosen.

Yes, you could certainly change the definitions of reflexivity etc. along those lines.  But why would you want to? The currently agreed definitions are extremely convenient. In what scenarios do your proposed changes contribute anything useful.

@RobArthan I understand that we can chose any definitions we like. I guess I'm trying to understand why the convention is to narrow the definition in this way so that it only applies to homogeneous relations? I thought it was fairly standard to establish definitions so that they applied as broadly as possible, but none of the sources I mentioned discuss properties of heterogenous relations, at all. I guess it's just not obvious to me why they wouldn't. Perhaps you could say more on why it is convenient to define them only for homogeneous relations?

I think we are mainly interested in the combinations of reflexivity, symmetry and transitivity that give us ordering relations and equivalence relations. In both of these cases, we have a particular set in mind that will be the universe of the relation. I don't think it is standard or a good rule of thumb to make definitions apply as broadly as possible (whatever that means).

Your proposed broadening of the definition really only makes sense in the context of material set theory, where we can talk about intersections of arbitrary sets. In more structural settings like type theory, you cannot even state reflexivity, transitivity or symmetry for heterogeneous relations. Most of mathematics is structural, despite being carried out in material foundations (a paradox we ought to resolve!).

The idea of making definitions in as broad a context as possible needs some care about "possible". When broadening a definition, one guideline is that the theorems proved under the older definition (or at least the most important theorems) should extend reasonably to the new definition. (Of course "important" and "reasonable" will depend on the intended purpose of the broadening.)
